# How to set "vcvarsall.bat" - Build output (target) architecture to "Any CPU"

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2015, x86-64, command-line-arguments

I am struggling to set the solution output to Any CPU for my projects when building from command line.

I have to use "vcvarsall.bat" (Dependency on the build structure, so I can not change this).

From Microsoft documentations present at [Build on the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160)

The solution to pass the architecture was available like:
architecture: x86
Compiler: x86 32-bit native
Host computer architecture: x86, x64
Build output (target) architecture: x86

But the option to pass Any CPU is not present in the list of arguments that are supported.

How do I pass the same. If I pass x86 my build fails with error that architecture expected is Any CPU and if I build with x64 the dll fails on 32 bit machine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, Is your issue that the options for `VsDevCmd.bat` offer x64, and x86 but not one for both? If so, what do you want us to help you with? If not, what do you want us to help you with?

Comment: The page you linked is about the C++ toolset, but "Any CPU" does not apply to C++ projects. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67566061/edit) the post with details about the type of project you are building, and quote the build command line and errors that you are getting.